# When is an étale map proper?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $Y\to X$ be étale and let both schemes be connected, and let $X$ be locally noetherian and geometrically unibranch, or normal.

How/under what assumptions can we prove that the map is proper?

A related thing I read somewhere stated that being proper was a local property and went on to assume that $X$ was noetherian and wanting to show that $Y$ was quasi-compact, but why would that imply that the map is proper?

Comment: In all reasonable cases, etale map is proper if and only if it is finite.

Comment: @Mohan that is a good equivalence, thank you. Do you have any reference for this claim or is it "super standard"? Sorry for asking easy questions

Comment: etale implies quasi-finite and proper + quasi-finite is stronger than proper + quasi-affine which is equal to finite. Do you know the book by Görtz and Wedhorn? They have a nice graphic torwards the end of their book, which summarizes these relations between properties of morphisms.

Answer (score 1):

To give a precise reference, finite is equivalent to proper + locally quasifinite (https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02LS). Etale morphisms are locally quasifinite (since they are locally given by standard etale morphisms https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02GH), so etale + proper implies etale + proper + locally quasifinite implies etale and finite.